# Is there a module for getting user input from the command line in node.js?

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface, npm

First of all: I don't mean parsing arguments and options from the `process.argv` array, but prompting the user and handling input/output. I've looked through the [Node.js official module list](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules) without finding any sections or subsections that mentions input. In fact a search for 'input' on that page only gets 1 result which has something to do with YAML.

Anyway, I suppose cli input should be asynchronous and I've solved this issue before using `stdin.on('data')` which was messy to say the least. This seems like a perfect task for a node module which could come with extra goodies such as progress bars, spinners, coloured output, input validation etc.

There probably are some modules out there that does this, but I can't find any of them.

Help!!

(To clarify, the only functionality I **require** is the simplification of handling user input)

Comment: I gave this an upvote, favorited it and shared it on both Facebook and Twitter, but now, please, append a "?" at your question!

Comment: I guess that slipped me by when I refactored the title. It started out as "Getting user input from the command line" :P

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Search for modules here: http://eirikb.github.com/nipster/

- Prompt: https://github.com/jesusabdullah/node-prompt
- Progress bar: https://github.com/substack/node-multimeter
- Colors: https://github.com/Marak/colors.js
- Input validation: https://github.com/chriso/node-validator
- More input validation (webbish tho): https://github.com/caolan/forms

Also, if you want to write your own: http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/all.html#readline

`#node.js` IRC welcomes you: http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=node.js

Comment: Brilliant answer, I wish I could vote it up ten times. Input validation is built in to prompt by the way